# How do I transform a column of values into possibly discrete training output classes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data

My dataset is a set of features and one column which is essentially views, each element of this column being an arbitrary positive real number, like the following.

Now in Python, I want to run a Keras  model on it. I plan to use this column as output labels for training the classifier.  The only solution I can think of is to scale it using sklearn and then conditionally somehow sort the scaled values into classes for enough training labels. Like for example, if 0.1 < views < 0.2: set_scale_to_0.1 and so on. Is this the best way to go about it?

```
+-------+

| Views |

+-------+

| 173   |

+-------+

| 943   |

+-------+
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? The dataset is well formatted, the OP-me has  invested time and resources in working on it himself.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are no signs of an attempt (as in, actual code), and nothing about programming that we can objectively focus on. Answers to "Is this the best way to go about it?" are often subjective, which we also discourage.

Comment: Fair enough. Point taken.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not trying to force this into a classification problem, but instead treating it as a regression. Two reasons:

**First**: your model targets (“labels” in classification) are not discrete, but integer valued.  This means that you will lose information with any effort to discretize them.

**Second**: classification is useful when labels being near each other does not contain information (like class 1 and 2 are no more similar than class 1 and 4). However, you want to gain information from data points that are near each other in terms of views.

So, you likely want to use regression. You can do this with Keras no problem; you just have to change the last layer (and possibly some other things, depending on your architecture). Try looking for “regression network” examples.

Comment: This makes sense, particularly the second point. But I read somewhere that lack of repetition in a classification/ regression problem leads to poor training.

There's also the issue that I'm trying to establish attribute importance to get a desirable subset of attributes. This changes things, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but what's the content of the `Views` column? Is it an annotation (classification) or a counter of something (regression)?

If it's a column which contains labels, you can convert each single value to a one hot encoder (see the example below). That final representation can be used as output layer to fit a neural network.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical

views = np.random.randint(3, size=10)
print(views)
# [0 1 2 1 0 1 1 2 1 0]

num_classes = len(set(views))
print(num_classes)
# 3

views = to_categorical(views, num_classes)
print(views)
# [[1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]]
```

Check https://keras.io/#getting-started-30-seconds-to-keras for an example. The variable `views` is `y_train`.

Comment: Youtube views. Random integer numbers. I'd say regression.